# The review queue empty message is missing the padding on the bottom (again)

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

As of 6/1/15, this bug is back again!

[image: Missing padding in the suggested edits queue]

---

A while ago (like a week, I think) the message for the review queue being empty was changed from

> There are no items for you to review

to

> This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review, view all review queues. 
>   Want to get back to the questions? Return to the Stack Overflow homepage.

all one line. I liked the newer message in that state.

Yesterday, it was changed slightly to the text below:

[image: Ugly review queue text]

> This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review, view all review queues.
>   Want to get back to the questions? Return to the Stack Overflow homepage.

The difference, while subtle, is annoying: There is a new line in the middle.  This also made the margin wonky.

It's very minor, but it was a minor change that made things worse.

To clarify, I don't mind the new line.  It's the wonky margins that annoy me.

Comment: I personally think the newline is better.

Comment: I don't mind the newline, but it is messing with the margins a bit and it looks odd.

Comment: Seems that the css class `.review-summary` has a `margin-top` of `10px`. Making it `3px` makes it _much_ better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this.  I agree the margins should be symmetric, but I opted for them to be 10px out of preference for a bit more whitespace.  Should be fixed in the next build.

Comment: The fix looks very good!

Comment: Seems the problem is back again.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like the newline. Keeps the "items" separated. However, I agree that the margins are "strange".

I did a quick poke around the page and it seems that the css class `.review-summary` has a `margin-top` of `10px`. If you make it `3px`, it looks *much* better..

```
.review-summary {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

> [image]

<sub>Note: I had to disable the entire css rule for a few classes to get this to work, so clearly I don't fully understand the css code base</sub>

Comment: For testing, I used `margin-top 3px !important`, and that showed what you want.